# disable django clasical auth and force ldap auth

Tags: django, ldap

I've got a django project where I've connected to an LDAP and I'm adding some users manually via the admin page with my superuser login.  The first user I added I created using the correct LDAP password.  Then to make sure I was logging in with the ldap user and not the django authentication method I changed the ldap password for the newly created user.  I can now login with both the ldap password and the original one.  Is there a way to disable django authentication method and force ldap?

I disabled 'django.contrib.auth' in the installed apps but that did not work.

Comment: which app do you use for ldap auth?

Comment: I did not put the ldap connection in an app I entered it in a local_settings.py which overirdes the settings.py using this method http://docs.geonode.org/en/master/tutorials/admin/ldap/

Comment: you use `django-auth-ldap` as written in the docs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which backends are called in which order is defined by `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` (the following snippet is taken from your linked docs)

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend',
)
```

Remove the backend shipped by `django.contrib.auth`:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend',
)
```

And it should behave like you want it to be.